# JQuery run function wait X time and then re-run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at jQuery and I really hope I can get help with this problem as it is causing me significant headache.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var global = '0'
    run(); // run function run on page load.

    function run(){
        var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
        var wait = new Array("2000", "5000", "10000");

        alert (cars[global]);

        WAIT (wait[global]) THEN run function cars AGAIN {
            run();
            global++;
            if (global == 4) {
                global = '0';   
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So as you can see: on page load function `run()` runs, alerting "Saab". THEN the function should wait 2000ms and re-run iself. On the next run function run would alert "Volvo" and wait 5000ms before re-running itself. On the third run it would alert "BWM" and wait 10000ms then resetting the global variable to 0 and doing it all over again.

So basically what I will do is populate the two arrays with different variables and create alerts based on user-defined delays.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use `setInterval` .

Comment: How? If I use a setInterval at 1000ms then it will run the function every 1000ms. The function should run at different times based on the values in the wait variable.

Comment: @binnathon Then use a count variable and `setTimeout`

Comment: Reform the two arrays to an array of objects to make it easier. Use the setTimeout method with the wait-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You mean *SetTimeout* that is used to run code after x amount of milliseconds ([here more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)).

Here is a working solution:

```
$(function() {
    var global = '0'
    run(); // run function run on page load.

    function run(){
        var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
        var wait = new Array("2000", "5000", "10000");      
        alert (cars[global]);

        setTimeout(function(){
            global++;
            if (global == 3){
                global = '0';   
            }
            run();
        }, wait[global]); 
    }
})
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32ep27zm/) to it.

I moved:

```
global++;
if (global == 3){
    global = '0';   
}
```

Before the function call as if the call is before increment, it would call the function with *global = 0* again first. If you are unsure what I mean by that, try with JSFiddle.

Just clean a bit the code (for fun), here is my code (same code blocks just rearranged):

```
$(function() {
    var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
    var wait = new Array("2000", "5000", "10000");

    var global = '0'
    run(); // Initial run.

    function run(){
        if (global == 3){
                global = '0';   
            }
        alert (cars[global]);
        global++;

        setTimeout(function(){
            run();
        }, wait[global]); 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout before running the function again with `window.setTimeout`.

Here is a recursive solution for your problem:

```
$(function() {
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    var wait = ["2000", "5000", "10000"];
    var index = 0;
    run();

    function run() {
        if(cars.length < index + 1 || wait.length < index + 1) {
            index = 0;
        }
        var car = cars[index];
        var waitingTime = wait[index];

        // do something with `car`
        console.log(car);

        index++;
        window.setTimeout(run, waitingTime);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var index = 0;
var cars = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var obj = {car: "Volvo", timeout: "2000"};
  cars.push(obj);
  var obj = {car: "Saab", timeout: "5000"};
  cars.push(obj);
  var obj = {car: "BMW", timeout: "10000"};
  cars.push(obj);

  alertAndReRun();
});

function alertAndReRun(){
    console.log(index + " " + (cars.length-1));

        alert(cars[index].car);
        index++;
    if(index <= (cars.length-1)){ 
        setTimeout(alertAndReRun, cars[index].timeout);
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This example works as you expected, using *setInterval()*

```
    $(function() {
        var timer = null;
        run();

        function run(){
            var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");

            console.log(cars[global]);

            global++;
            if (global == 3) {
                global = 0;   
            }

            if (timer !== null) { 
                clearInterval(timer);
            }

            timer = setInterval(run, parseInt(wait[global]));
        }
    });
```

And here a JSFiddle: [Time Variable interval](https://jsfiddle.net/wptezfex/)

Comment: You are misusing the function `setInterval()`: On every interval iteration, you break the interval again. Exactly for this use case, there is the function `setTimeout()`

Comment: I use setInterval() in this example to make it more flexible and to post another possible solution @ssc-hrep3 You are right, anyway by theory.